# Inner Join on Two Select Statements SQL

Tags: database

Suppose I have a table with a student's name and grades. I want to create a query which tells me, for each student, what percentage of his grades were above a 75. Different students may have taken different number of tests.

For example:

1. Joe 49
2. Joe 80
3. Joe 100
4. Bob 90
5. Bob 100
6. Bob 95
7. Bob 91
8. Sam 74
9. Sam 76

Would return

1. Joe 0.67
2. Bob 1.0
3. Sam 0.5

Comment: Is it supposed to be sqlite or did you select that dialect by accident?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assuming your schema is:

```
user_grades
username: varchar(255)
grade: int
```

Then I would do this query

```
SELECT 
    user_grades.username, 
    round(grades_above.total / user_grades.total,2) percent_above 
FROM (
    SELECT username, count(*) total FROM user_grades GROUP BY 1
)  user_grades
INNER JOIN (SELECT username, count(*) total FROM user_grades WHERE grade > 75 
GROUP BY 1) grades_above ON user_grades.username = grades_above.username
```

There is probably more than one way to do it but that's done with two select statements and an inner join. I think the example results are wrong but here's what I would expect to see.

```
username    percent_above
Bob         1.00
Joe         0.67
Sam         0.50
```

But just make sure you understand what's going on and let me know if you have any questions. It's more important you understand how to get the answer than the answer itself.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like s homework assignment, which you need to solve yourself. Perhaps you need to start by looking at how to break this problem down into steps. For example:

- 1) Write a query to return your first set of data (you probably have
  this already) and count how many tests each student has completed
- 2)
  Write a query to and count how many tests each student has completed
  that are above the threshold (75)
- 3) Write a query that joins the
  results of the above queries and gives you the desired output

The last step is where the join comes in

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
Select  studentName
,Round(Count(grade) /sum(case when grade>75 then 1 else 0 End),2) as persentage 
from studentsTable 
group by studentName
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this for a start

```
SELECT name,
COUNT(*) AS over_75
FROM student
WHERE grade > 75
GROUP BY name;
```